# Difficulties solving this integral: $ \int_0^1 \frac{\ln(x+1)} {x^2 + 1} \, \mathrm{d}x $ by differentiation under the integral sign

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, definite-integrals

So in the book Advanced Calculus Explored, by Hamza E. Asamraee. The next integral appears as an exercise to solve by differentiating under the integral sign:

$$ \int_0^1 \frac{\ln(x+1)} {x^2 + 1} \, \mathrm{d}x $$

I have solved this integral before by substitution and change in the limits of integration, but in this chapter the book asks to solve it by differentiation under the integral sign. I have tried several ways of solving this, but the only one that i thought it was leading me somewhere was:

$$f(a) = \int_0^1 \frac{\ln(x+a)} {x^2 + 1} \, \mathrm{d}x $$

So that:

$$f'(a) = \int_0^1 \frac{1} {(x+a)(x^2 + 1)} \, \mathrm{d}x $$

Then i tried to separate this last integral by partial fractions, my result on this was:

$$\frac {1} {(x+a)(x^2 + 1)} = \frac{1} {a^2 + 1} \left(\frac {1} {x+a} - \frac{x-a} {x^2+1}\right)$$

And the integral reduces to:

$$f'(a) = \int_0^1 \frac{1} {a^2 + 1} \left(\frac {1} {x+a} - \frac{x-a} {x^2+1} \right) \, \mathrm{d}x $$

Then this last expression evaluates to:

$$f'(a) = \frac{1} {a^2 + 1} (\ln(a+1) - \ln(a) - \ln(4)+ \frac{π}{4} a)$$

Then integrating from 0 to 1 with respect to $a$ we will get:

$$f(1) - f(0) = \int_0^1 \frac{\ln(a+1)} {a^2 + 1} \, \mathrm{d}a - \int_0^1 \frac{\ln(a)} {a^2 + 1} \, \mathrm{d}a $$

(The last two terms of $f'(a)$ cancel each other after the integration so i didn't wrote them)

But then the two integrals on the right hand side are equal to $f(1) - f(0)$ so the differentiation under the integral led nowhere.

Do i need some other approach? Or did i made any mistake?
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would work:
$$I(a) = \int_0^1 \frac{\ln(ax+1)}{x^2+1} dx \\ 
I’(a) =\int_0^1 \frac{x}{(x^2+1)(ax+1)} dx \\ \overset{\text{partial fractions}}= \\ \frac{-2\ln |ax+1| +\ln(x^2+1)+2a\tan^{-1} x}{2(a^2+1)} \bigg |_0^1 \\ =-\frac{\ln(a+1)}{a^2+1}+\frac{\ln 2}{2a^2+2}+\frac{\pi}{4} \frac{a}{a^2+1}
$$
Integrating from $0$ to $1$, $$I(1)-I(0) = -I(1) +\int_0^1 \left(\frac{\ln 2}{2a^2+2}+\frac{\pi}{4} \frac{a}{a^2+1}\right) da$$

Hopefully you can finish.

Comment: Aren't you missing $I(0)$ on the right hand side of the last equation?

Comment: @SamHaze I don’t think so.

Comment: Oh shit know i see, thanks your answer was great!

Answer (score 1):

Even if I think that @Tavish's solution is the most efficient, wht you did must work.

$$f(a) = \int_0^1 \frac{\log(x+a)} {x^2 + 1}  \,dx$$
$$f'(a) = \frac{1} {a^2 + 1} \left(\log(a+1) - \log(a) - \ln(4)+ \frac{\pi}{4} a\right)$$ Now, you must use $a^2+1=(a+i)(a-i)$ to make
$$ \int f'(a)\,da=\frac{1}{8} \pi  \log \left(a^2+1\right)+\frac{1}{2} i \text{Li}_2(-i
   a)-\frac{1}{2} i \text{Li}_2(i a)-$$ $$\frac{1}{2} i
   \text{Li}_2\left(\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{i}{2}\right) (a+1)\right)+\frac{1}{2} i
   \text{Li}_2\left(\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i}{2}\right) (a+1)\right)-$$ $$\frac{1}{2} i
   \log ((1+i)-(1-i) a) \log (a+1)+\frac{1}{2} i \log (-(1+i) (a+i)) \log
   (a+1)-$$ $$\log (a) \tan ^{-1}(a)-\frac{1}{2} \log (2) \tan ^{-1}(a)$$

$$ \int_0^1 f'(a)\,da=\frac{1}{2} (2 C-i (\text{Li}_2(1-i)-\text{Li}_2(1+i))+\pi  \log (2))-\frac{1}{2} i
   \left(\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i}{2}\right)-\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{1}{
   2}-\frac{i}{2}\right)\right)=C+\frac{1}{8} \pi  \log (2)$$ Since
$$\int_0^1 \frac{\log(x)} {x^2 + 1}  \,dx=-C$$ then the result.

Comment: Oh right, thanks for the answer! But i was trying to solve it without the $Li$ function or without complex numbers

Answer (score -1):

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{(x+a)(x^2+1)}=$$
$$\frac{A}{x+a}+\frac{Bx+C}{x^2+1}$$

we find that $$A=\frac{1}{a^2+1}$$

and

$$Bi+C=\frac{1}{a+i}=\frac{a-i}{a^2+1}$$

So,

$$B=-\frac{1}{a^2+1}\;,\;C=\frac{a}{a^2+1}$$

Comment: That's the same procedure and reults i used

Comment: @SamHaze Did you use complex number $ i $.

Comment: No, but i am using the same values of A, B and  C